# Como aumentar a fonte e cursor da barra input="text" de acordo com o tamanho desejado?

Tags: html, css, input

Apliquei um padding de 30px e o cursor e a fonte da input="text" não aumentou conforme o espaçamento interno aplicado, existe alguma possibilidade de aumentar o tamanho conforme o desejado?? tentei aplicar um 'font-size'  mas! conforme aumenta a fonte a bendita barra também aumenta seu grau, queria aumentar a fonte e a barra ficar do tamanho que estar aí,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM6rI.png

```css
table{ border-spacing:0px; border:1px solid #000; 
}
td{ border:1px solid #000; padding:30px;
}
tr{
}
td.spc{ position:absolute; left:535px;
}
td.sp{ position:relative; width:800px;
}
td.nm{ position:absolute; left:1050px; border-right:none;
}
td#br{ position: absolute; z-index:1; border:none;  
}
input[type=text]{-webkit-appearance:none; outline-color:#F00;padding:30px; border:2px solid #03F;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

<table>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-1</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td id="br"><input type="text"/></td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">1</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-2</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">2</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-3</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">3</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-4</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">4</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Já pensou em adicionar o width/height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table{ border-spacing:0px; border:1px solid #000; 
}
td{ border:1px solid #000; padding:30px;
}
tr{
}
td.spc{ position:absolute; left:535px;
}
td.sp{ position:relative; width:800px;
}
td.nm{ position:absolute; left:1050px; border-right:none;
}
td#br{ position: absolute; z-index:1; border:none;  
}
input[type=text]{-webkit-appearance:none; outline-color:#F00;padding:30px;border:2px solid #03F;box-sizing: border-box;font-size:50px;max-width:240px
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

<table>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-1</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td id="br"><input type="text"/></td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">1</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-2</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">2</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-3</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">3</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-4</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">4</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Adiciona um max-width e muda o box-sizing

Answer (score 1):

Defina um `height` fixo para o input:

```
height: 30px
```

Após isso defina o `font-size`:

```
font-size: 40px;
```

Seu próprio código:

```css
table{ border-spacing:0px; border:1px solid #000; 
}
td{ border:1px solid #000; padding:30px;
}
tr{
}
td.spc{ position:absolute; left:535px;
}
td.sp{ position:relative; width:800px;
}
td.nm{ position:absolute; left:1050px; border-right:none;
}
td#br{ position: absolute; z-index:1; border:none;  
}
input[type=text]{-webkit-appearance:none; outline-color:#F00;padding:30px; border:2px solid #03F;height:25px !important;font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

<table>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-1</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td id="br"><input type="text"/></td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">1</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-2</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">2</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-3</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">3</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>BLOCO-4</td><td>SERVIÇO</td><td class="spc">Section</td><td class="nm">4</td><td class="sp"></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

PS: o `font-size` também irá modificar o `width`, considere definir um `width` fixo ou com porcentagem, exemplo:

```
width:200px;
```